# Restrict users from creating new opportunities directly at an 'order' (closed won) stage in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I'm stuck with creating a validation rule where I'd like to restrict my users from creating new opportunities directly at 'order' (closed won) stage. 
We do have a validation rule currently running which restricts users from changing an opportunity stage to order (from any other stage) (only some specific users can change the status to order).

Looks like when they create a new opp directly with the stage as 'order/closed won' , they are able to do so. I'd like to restrict this.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks,
Priyanka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is that PRIORVALUE only works with updates. The following formula might work:

```
OR(<current_rule>, AND(ISNEW(), ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Order')))
```

Comment: Thanks :) Actually, got it to work with the below validation rule.. AND (ISNEW(), (ISPICKVAL( StageName ,"Order")))

Answer (score 0):

You could use your existing rule or create a new rule that checks if the record is new (ISNEW()) and never allow a new record to be created with "order/closed won" stage.